# How to read date and time from json data and set reminders

Tags: android, datetime, alarmmanager

I have a JSON object containing date and time information, I want to retrieve the date and set reminders based on the date/time.

```
{"Data":[{Remindercurdate=2017-06-22 09:48:25, Reminder=dtyhnnfg}]}
```

Comment: `retrieve the date` and `set reminders` are 2 different tasks. Which one is a problem for you? You shouldn't ask multiple questions in one question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving the whole solution code, but here you can find the more information about [parsing the json object in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)
and after retrieving the data from the json file you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to set the reminder based on time. Then use the [Broadcast Receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) that gets the alarm do whatever you want (vibrate, send a notification, etc). Here is working the [example](https://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/).